# Real time core plot IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, charts, core-plot

I am using the core plot framework to make a real time chart. The problem is that after a while it freezes my iphone . I think is because of the large number of data and that i reload it every time  i get new data. I need a solution to this. I though of setting a timer and reloading every 5 sec or so or maybe using a parallel thread.What should i do.Thanks.

I am talking about maybe 2-3000.

Here is my code:

```
//graph1 init
CGRect graphRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 183);
graph=[[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:graphRect];

CPGraphHostingView *graphView = (CPGraphHostingView*)graphViewScroll;
graphView.hostedGraph = graph;

graph.paddingLeft = 20.0;
graph.paddingTop = 20.0;
graph.paddingRight = 20.0;
graph.paddingBottom = 20.0;

CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0)
                                               length:CPDecimalFromFloat(17)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0)
                                               length:CPDecimalFromFloat(25)];


CPMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
lineStyle.lineWidth = 1.5f;
lineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor whiteColor];



CGRect speedframe=CGRectMake(305,70, 50, 15);


UILabel *speedlabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:speedframe];
speedlabel.text=@"Speed";
speedlabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
speedlabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
speedlabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( M_PI/2 );


CGRect metersframe=CGRectMake(615,80, 70, 15);


UILabel *meterslabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:metersframe];
meterslabel.text=@"Meters";
if([distance1 isEqualToString:@"miles"]) {
    meterslabel.text=@"Feet";
}

meterslabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
meterslabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
meterslabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( M_PI/2 );

CGRect speedframe1=CGRectMake(450,165, 90, 15);


UILabel *timelabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:speedframe1];

timelabel.text=@"Time";
timelabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
timelabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
//timelabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( M_PI/2 );

CGRect kmframe=CGRectMake(770,165, 90, 15);


UILabel *kmlabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:kmframe];
kmlabel.text=@"Km";
if([distance1 isEqualToString:@"miles"]) {
    kmlabel.text=@"Miles";
}
kmlabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
kmlabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1"] decimalValue];
axisSet.xAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;

//axisSet.xAxis.axisTitle=@"Test";
//axisSet.xAxis.axisLabelOffset = 3.0f;

axisSet.yAxis.majorIntervalLength = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"3"] decimalValue];
axisSet.yAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
//axisSet.yAxis.axisLabelOffset = 3.0f;

CPScatterPlot *xInversePlot = [[[CPScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
xInversePlot.identifier = @"X Inverse Plot 1";
lineStyle = [[xInversePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy] autorelease];
lineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
lineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor whiteColor];
xInversePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
xInversePlot.dataSource = self;
[graph addPlot:xInversePlot];

//graph1 end
```

I have two charts.
Here i put data in the chart:

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot{
if(plot.identifier == @"X Inverse Plot 2") {
    return [contentArray count];
}
else {
    return [dataForPlot count];
}
 }

 -(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

//NSLog(@"numar:%@",num);
if(plot.identifier == @"X Inverse Plot 2") {
    NSLog(@"X Inverse Plot 2");
     NSNumber *num = [[self.contentArray objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:(fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldX ? @"x" : @"y")];
    return num;
}
else {
      NSNumber *num = [[self.dataForPlot objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:(fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldX ? @"x" : @"y")];
    return num;
}
}
```

And i reload the data every time i get a new data from the gps.

Comment: Please show your code where you load the data. Also please clarify by what you mean by "large number of data." 100 units? 1000 units? 100000 units? Let us know as much about the problem as possible and it will help us figure out what should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

See [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss/browse_thread/thread/da171b1e02a3881f#) on the Core Plot discussion board for some ideas to improve your data loading performance.

I would recommend against trying to load data on a separate thread. Core Plot isn't designed to be multi-threaded and other users have reported problems doing so.